# Are the objects well-defined in $P_{*}(X)\circ P^{-1}: s \in S \to(P_*X)_{P^{-1}(s)} \in T_s S$?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am trying to make sense of the following statement:

Let $P: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3} $ be a  parameterized surface. Let $S=Im(P)$
Suppose $P$ is injective. If $X$ is a vector field over $\Omega$,

$P_{*}(X)\circ P^{-1}: s \in S \to(P_*X)_{P^{-1}(s)} \in T_s S$ is a vector field over $S$

where $P_{*}$ is the tangent mapping of P, $T_s S$ is the tangent space of $S$ at $s$

**I think the objects are not well-defined:**

1. The composition $P_{*}(X)\circ P^{-1}$ makes no sense. $P_*(X)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R^3} $, so it is a mapping $ \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3} $ , while $P^{-1}:  \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2} $, therefore I can't compose them
2. $(P_*X)_{P^{-1}(s)} \in T_s S$ makes no sense. It is supposed to mean the vector field $P_{*}(X)$  at point $P^{-1}(s)$ , but  $P_{*}(X)$ is a vector field over  $\mathbb{R^3} $, while $P^{-1}(s)\in \mathbb{R^2}$. I need a point in $\mathbb{R^3}$ where the field $P_{*}(X)$lives, not in $\mathbb{R^2}$ where the field $X$ lives.

What is going on here?

Comment: What would make more sense is $(P_*X)_s$, which is the value of the push-forward vector field at the point $s$. Or by moving the parentheses a little, $P_*(X_{P^{-1}(s)})$ would also make sense. You take the value of the vector field $X$ at $P^{-1}(s)$, and then push it forward.

Comment: @Nick Are $P_{*}(X)$  and $P_{*}X$ different? Since $P_{*}$ is a function I think I need the "( )", so the second one makes no sense, unless $P_{*}$ is the matrix of the linear mapping, but I am not sure if I can just confuse both interpretations

Comment: It is standard notation in differential geometry to just use $P_*X$ instead of $P_*(X)$.

Comment: @Nick , so is $(P_*X)_{P^{-1}(s)}$ definitely wrong?

Comment: Yes, I agree that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nick What about the composition $P_{*}(X)\circ P^{-1}$? Do you agree it makes no sense, either?

Comment: Yes, I agree. It was probably just bad notation, intended to mean what I said above.